# Images not clickable

Tags: html, css

Why are these images not clickable? The last image works, but the first two don't at all

```
<div class="main-logo"> 
    <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/logo.png" alt="MCMonthly Logo" style="width:776px;height:201px;" />  
</div> 

<div class="button-points"> 
    <a href="/points"> <img class="points-img" src="/assets/button_points.png" alt="Points button" style="width:300px;height:300px;" /></a>  
</div> 

<div class="button-games">
  <a href="/games"> <img class="games-img" src="/assets/button_games.png" alt="Games button" style="width:300px;height:300px;" /></a>  
</div> 

<div class="button-tos"> 
    <a href="/tos"> <img class="tos-img" src="/assets/button_tos.png" alt="TOS button" style="width:300px;height:300px;" /></a>  
</div>
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure that all but the first image would be clickable if you were to copy paste that code into an empty HTML file. The first one isn’t wrapped in a <a>. Please provide more information.

Comment: Your first image is *NOT* wrapped in an anchor tag `<a>//image code here</a>` the last three divs work without issue, your question is not reproducible.